# apache restart command in linux?

Tags: linux, apache

I restart my apache on centos,
I cd the apache bin dir
use

```
apachectl restart
```

It's no working 
but 
I use

```
 /dir..../bin/apachectl restart
```

It's working ,why??

[image]

Comment: type >whereis apachectl     then look where it shows

Comment: it shows  "apachectl:"

Comment: sorry you should type >which apachetl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apachectl` may not be on your PATH so your OS doesn't know what that command is or where it is (even though you `cd` into the folder).

If you provide a path to the command Linux will know what to do with it.

If you `cd` into the folder and do `./apachectl restart` it should work as well.

Answer (score 2):

you type >`which apachetl,`

if result is such below

```
/usr/bin/which: no lsasd in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/turkcell/wlsadmin/bin)
```

you have to add its full path to `PATH` enviroment in order to execute command at any directory.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/services/apache2-2/bin
```